# How to receive datalist item when sender is html button?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

In my DataList I want a button to be displayed with a FA icon, so I used a html button and made it runat="server", now when I click the button I want to know which Datalist Item is 'bounded' with this button.

I tried to use a asp.net button, but I can't use FA icons then.

This is what my html and c# code looks like:

```
<asp:DataList Width="100%" ID="dtlFAQSections" runat="server" DataSourceID="dtsFAQSections" DataKeyField="FAQSectionID">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <h2>
             <button id="btnFAQSection" runat="server" onserverclick="btnFAQSection_Click" style="background-color:#f24646; border:none; color:white; margin-left:25px; font-size:16px; cursor:pointer; height: 26px; width: 26px; margin-right: 5px; border-radius:30%;"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
             <asp:Label Font-Size="18px" ID="FAQSectionNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FAQSectionName") %>' />
         </h2>
         <hr style="border: 1px dotted #000000; border-style: none none dotted; color: #fff; background-color: #fff;"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

```c#
protected void btnFAQSection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)btn.NamingContainer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use `HtmlButton` since you are not using an ASP control as a Button. Then simply find the Parent.

```
protected void btnFAQSection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlButton btn = (HtmlButton)sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)btn.NamingContainer;

    //now you can access the DataListItem
    Label label = item.FindControl("FAQSectionNameLabel") as Label;
    label.Text = "DataListItem Found";

    //or if you want to get the parent DataList
    DataList dl = btn.Parent.Parent as DataList;

    Label1.Text = dl.ID;
}
```